# enable submit button after validation the form in jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm using [Jquery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/), In my web page i want to do this scenario , the submit button is disabled by default but when the form is validated i want to enable the submit button , i'm doing as below, but the button was not enabled after the form was validated, is something missing

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#save').attr('disabled', true);

  $('#myform').validate({

    errorClass: 'error',
    success: function() {
      $('#save').attr('disabled', false);
    },

    rules: {
      termsCons: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      termsCons: {
        required: "${message(code:'sherif.jqueryValidation.required')}"
      },
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $('#save').attr('disabled', false);

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: jQuery validation will prevent submit of the form unless all rules evaluate valid, no need to disable the button. Let the user click it and show the validation message if needed below the relevant controls. It's common practice. You have to validate anyway seeing anyone can open the console and just do `$('#save').prop('disabled', false);` or similar and then click the button.

Comment: @Fran but i want to do an extra validation by disabling the submit button and enabling it once the form is valid

Comment: You can trigger `validate` in that case on every keyup and/or blur for every relevant control on your form. See the linked duplicate on how to implement this.